# gdal2tiles -e giving error about Processing of several input files is not supported received?

Tags: gdal2tiles

I'm using gdal2tiles for tile huge geoTIFF image. The problem is that only 1 core cpu was being used so I stopped the process for use the -np_processes param to try use paralellism beacuse there have spent 3 days and still running... Now when I'm trying to run again the comand line for continue the tiling process, I'm using the "-e" param to resume and don't remake the tiles already created, but I'm receiving the error:

> gdal2tiles.py: error: Processing of several input files is not
>   supported. Please first use a tool like gdal_vrtmerge.py or
>   gdal_merge.py on the files: gdal_vrtmerge.py -o merged.vrt 4

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Hi! welcome to GIS SE! Could you please share the command you are using? It should look similar to: `gdal2tiles.py -p mercator -w all -r average -a ` etc..

Comment: sure, here is my command line:gdal2tiles.py -e -p geodetic -nb_processes 4 -k -v -w google image.tif TILES/

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score -1):

Done!!! It was all about the way I was passing the `np_processes` param.

The correct way is: `-nb_processes=4`, not `nb_processes 4`

Comment: This is not answer to your question but to your original problem https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/324302/gdal2tiles-py-using-param-nb-processes-does-not-use-multicore-only-one-core-f