# gdal2tiles.py using param: -nb_processes does not use multicore, only one core fully working

Tags: gdal2tiles

I'm using gdal2tiles to tile huge geoTIFF image, but it takes a long time. I tried using the `nb_processes` param but only one core is working hard.

My command line:

```
gdal2tiles.py -e -p geodetic -nb_processes=4 -k -v -w google image.tif TILES/
```

How can I achieve multicore tiling?

Comment: Have you gone past creating the base tiles? I am remembering that setting does not affect generating tiles for the lower zoom levels. And where did you take your syntax with -nb_processes? By https://gdal.org/programs/gdal2tiles.html the usage is  `--processes=4`.

Comment: I found my answer at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7743/performance-of-google-map-tile-creation-processes. Thanks a lot